# how to show some widgets based on the selection from one widget in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

below is a shiny app to upload a rda or csv file.  What I need is only show the checkboxinput and radiobutton widgets only when  csv is selected as the file type in the selectinput. When rda is selected, do not show those widgets.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

##---------------------------------------------------------------
## ui
##---------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

                # select a file type
                selectInput('filetype', label = h5(strong('Please select a file type')),
                            choices = c('rda', 'csv'),
                            selected = 'rda'),

                # Input: Select a file ----
                fileInput("file1", "Choose a file",
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          accept = c("text/csv",
                                     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                     ".csv")),

                tags$hr(),

                # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
                checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

                # Input: Select separator ----
                radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                             choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                         Semicolon = ";",
                                         Tab = "\t"),
                             selected = ","),


                # Input: Select quotes ----
                radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                             choices = c(None = "",
                                         "Double Quote" = '"',
                                         "Single Quote" = "'"),
                             selected = '"')

        ),


        #------------------------------Main Panel--------------------    
        mainPanel(

            DT::dataTableOutput("data.table")

        )
    )
)


##---------------------------------------------------------------------
# server 
##---------------------------------------------------------------------
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {


    dt <- reactive ({

        if (input$filetype %in% 'rda') {
            load (input$file1$datapath)
            df  
        } else {
            read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                     header = input$header,
                     sep = input$sep,
                     quote = input$quote)
        }

    })

    output$data.table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        req(input$file1)
        DT::datatable(dt(),
                      options = list(orderClasses = TRUE,
                    lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 20), pageLength = 5))
    })

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Really appreciate it if anyone can help me with that. I have no clue how to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample of how to do build a dynamic UI that will only show the radio buttons if the file type selected is 'csv'. Refer to https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html for more.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "select",
    label = "File Type",
    choices = list("csv", "rda"),
    selected = c("csv")
  ),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.select == 'csv'",
    radioButtons(
      "radio",
      label = "Separator",
      choices = list("commas", "tabs", "spaces")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```